# excel data validation list only upper case

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, data-validation

I want to do some data validation in my excel workbook. I want to use as many centralized values as possible for the data validation as the same values are used for multiple sheets. Now I have added some validation for Currency codes (USD...). the validation is based on a list in another sheet and its working kinda good. my problem is that I can still enter lower case values and not just exact values. I would prefer a solution which does not use VBA is possible. If its only possible with VBA, then please add some information on how to add it to the workbook and such.

The values i want to allow are:

```
CHF
EUR
GBP
USD
DKK
SEK
NOK
```

and the data validation looks like this: `=Sheet1!$S$2:$S$8` but also allows the values above as lower case which is not what i want (i see that i can list the values inside the data validation and then it only accepts exact matches, but for the sake of not having much work if the values change, i want to have them centralized).

I think it would be also good enough to convert the values into upper case, but it has to happen in the same cell eg. I enter `eur` in cell `J6` then it should convert the value to upper case and write it also in `J6`

Comment: If you type a list in the combo box instead of using a range, then it *should* match the case.

Comment: Is your input area a coherent range?

Comment: @mcalex thats true, but if i want to add/delete a value, its much work. ideally i would have like 100 cells as validation range, but only the non blank cells should show up (no blank values in list even if just 5 of 100 cells contain a value). also it should match case sensitive with cell reference in use

Comment: @IQV its a named range, but i thought about using a named table, but i can't reference the tables from the data validation wizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with VBA:
Do a right-click on the tab of your worksheet and chose "Show code...". In the VBA-Editor enter these macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C100")) Is Nothing Then
         On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
         Application.EnableEvents = False
         Target.Value = UCase(Target)
    ErrorHandler:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Change the range corresponding to your needs. You have to save your file as `*.xlsm`. Then every text in the range is converted to uppercase.

Comment: the range is basically the column right? the range starts at J6 and goes as long as needed. so i would change the range to `J6:J`?

Comment: You can use `J:J`.

Comment: well, the column has a header in line 3 which does not match any values and therefore i would lik to just start at row 6 because there the data starts

Comment: Then you have to use `J6:J1048576` or a line number for the end which fits your needs.

Comment: to enable the functionality for several worksheets i have to add the code for each sheet right?

Comment: Need some time to check and test it...

Comment: nvm just added it to each sheet manually because the columns differs. thanks anyways. now i have the value be checked by the list and if it works it will be converted to uppercase

Answer (score 1):

If the cell you want to validate is in cell A1, set your Data Validation type to **Custom** instead of List and paste this formula in:

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(--((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>64)),--(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<91))=LEN(A1),--(IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$S$2:$S$8,0),1),0)))
```

**Walkthrough**

This formula uses two conditions, combined with an `AND()` - firstly a check of whether the value is all upper case, secondly a check that the value matches your list of permitted options.

```
 =AND(
    SUMPRODUCT(
       --(
           (CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>64)
         )
       ,--(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<91)
     )=LEN(A1)
   ,--(IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$S$2:$S$8,0),1),0)))
```

The bits that look like `CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>64` are checking the ASCII code for each individual character. If they're between ASCII codes 64 and 91 we know they are upper case. If the number of upper cases characters matches the length of the value string, we know they are all upper case.

The `MATCH()` part checks the value appears in your list of currencies.

**Note:** Shoutout to [this post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=26963&p=146624#post146624) for the upper case check.

Comment: i get an error when i try to use the forumla as data validation in custom: there is a problem with this formula.`=AND(PRODUCT(--((CODE(MID(W6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(W6))),1))>64)),--(CODE(MID(W6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(W6))),1))<91))=LEN(W6),--(IFERROR(IF(MATCH(W6,Sheet1!$S$2:$S$8,0),1),0)))` should be right for an example

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you seem to have a typo early in the formula. It should be `SUMPRODUCT(...`, not `PRODUCT(...`. Everything else looks ok.

Comment: Also if you wanted to replace `Sheet1!$S$2:$S$8` with a named range so you don't have to edit the range as you add new values, you can do that.